# Cross-Origin Request Blocked Vue3 Asp.Net API 6.0 Nginx status 200

Tags: nginx, asp.net-web-api, cors, vuejs3

When I try calling the api endpoint from the UI on a live domain, the api call fails with a CORS error. The error is posted above, but is still returning a status 200?

This endpoint is called to authenticate the application. It returns the token and there is still a CORS error. I have added CORS configuration to the nginx config files but still have the same error occur.

[image]

Nginx Web API

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   api.MYDOMAIN.com www.api.MYDOMAIN.com;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    # RSA certificate
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.MYDOMAIN.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.MYDOMAIN.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

    # Redirect non-https traffic to https
    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Nginx UI server

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name pro.MYDOMAIN.com www.pro.MYDOMAIN.com;


    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        # RSA certificate
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/pro.MYDOMAIN.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/pro.MYDOMAIN.com/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

  
    # autoindex on;
    root /var/www/html/pro.MYDOMAIN.com/dist;
    index index.html;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Asp.net Web Api
[image]

The api call in Vue 3

```
      const response = await axios
        .post(
          `${API_URL}/Auth/Authenticate`,
          formData,
          { withCredentials: true },
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
              "user-agent": "My Pro",
              // "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true,
              // "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
            },
          }
        )
        .then((response) => {
          console.log('response in the then')
          console.log(response)
          return response
        })
        .catch((error) => {
        
          console.error(error);
          this.isLoggedIn = false;
          this.loginUnSuccessful = true;
        });
```